# async await Possible EventEmitter memory leak problems puppeteer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, puppeteer

Im currently building a web scraper with puppeteer and I've ran into some problems.

while the program was able to produce the result I want it ran into some problems. If I only call it once it behaves the way I want it to be but when I use setInterval() to make it recall itself it sends back errors and the heroku I deployed it on soon crashes.

EX.
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

my code is as follow

```
async function scrapeProduct(url) {
                  try {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  ],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
process.once('unhandledRejection', () => {
  browser.close();
});

await page.goto(url);
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {

  let List = []
  const result = document.querySelectorAll("div.prod_info");
  result.forEach(ele => {
    try {
      if (ele.querySelector('ul.price_box > li > span.site_btn.orderNow > button') !== null || ele.querySelector('ul.price_box > li > span.site_btn.add24hCart > button') !== null) {
        const GraphicCard = {
          'name': ele.querySelector('a').innerText,
          'price': ele.querySelector('.value').innerText,
          'link': ele.querySelector('a').href
        }
        List.push(GraphicCard);
      }
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }

  });
  return List;
})
browser.close();
return textContent;
 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
}

async function createList() {
  try {
       GList= []
const [1,2,3,4,5,6] = await Promise.all([scrapeProduct(url),<--*6])
GList.push(1,2,3,4,5,6)}
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('refresh')
  createList() 
}, 45000)
```

I really could not figure out what went wrong and searched all over the web but still could not resolve this.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Currently each `scrapeProduct()` call creates a browser process, this can be excessive. Try to reuse single browser instance just creating new pages (or even reuse the same pool of pages).

Comment: thank you both for providing solid solutions they were much apricated! I did manage to fix my app accordingly but now Im facing a new problem with heroku please take a look if you can  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759124/puppeteer-failed-when-deployed-to-heroku